# Redeploying a .net click once application fails with error "application cannot be started. contact the application vendor."

Tags: .net-3.5, citrix

Details in the error say "Cannot make this application an online application because the previous version is installed.  To install this application uninstall the previous version, or mark this application as installed."

Comment: @eschneider: Her question is, "How do I redeploy a .NET click-once application when I make changes to it, without running afoul of the error message stated above?"

Comment: Does anyone know how to "... mark this application as installed"?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx?ppud=4

Microsoft:

These are generic error messages that occur when the application cannot be started, and no other specific reason can be found. Frequently this means that the application is somehow corrupted, or that the ClickOnce store is corrupted.

Comment: I have the application installed on the main server as clickonce online only. Users access the application from citrix terminal servers (7 of them) on 6 of the 7 the application runs perfectly but one terminal server gets the error I mentioned above. 
What I think I need to know is how do I uninstall the application completely from the server and start over.

Comment: Try the windows control panel / Programs & Feature (Add remove programs)
Then look for you app.

Citrix may require you to login as a special account.